# How to get python packages installed for 32 bit before but works on 64bit as well in Visual Code? E.g. Pytorch

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pytorch

I use
(1) Windows 11,

(2) Python 3.7.8 for 64bit ;
Python 3.8.3 for 32bit

(3) Visual Studio Code.

I noticed that all my python packages are installed on 32Bit, **is there any way to get my packages works on 64bit as well?** Because I wish to use **Pytorch**, however, it only works on 64bit

I also installed **PyTorch** in Visual code, but it does not appear installed in my python environment...Why?

I tried to install **PyTorch** by pip and it gives me error as below:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have selected `Python3.7.8(64)` in the jupyter notebook, while you have installed the python modules in the `Python3.8.3(32)` environment. So it will prompt `No module named 'pandas'`.

And looks like torch has no 32bit version, if you want to use it, you need to select `Python3.7.8(64)`.

So, you can activate the terminal first through open a python file and then clicking the python interpreter on the bottom-right of the VSCode or choosing `Python: Select Python interpreter` in the command palette directly.

Then take the shortcut of **Ctrl+Shift+`** to create a new terminal with the activated python environment. After this, you can install the modules in the right place.

You can refer to the [official docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-and-activate-an-environment) for more detail.